# MySQL 5.7 - ASCII Each Character in a String

Tags: mysql, ascii

I'm looking to do some validation of data replication between some different database systems, with different character sets (potentially) and a third party software that migrates the data. To help test an aspect of this, I'm looking to do something like the following.

`ASCII(foo)` returns the value for the first character in the string. Is there a way to get the ascii values for all characters in a string in one go, in one select statement? Something like concating the values together, separated by a space. E.g. If the string was `hello` then the output would be `104 101 108 108 111`

**Reference:**

```
select ascii('h'); -- 104
select ascii('e'); -- 101
select ascii('l'); -- 108
select ascii('o'); -- 111
```

Comment: Why not hash the string and compare hashes?

Comment: There's nothing built-in, but you can easily write a function that does it, by looping over the length the string and calling `ASCII(SUBSTR(string, index, 1))`.

Comment: @bishop thanks for the idea. I think as long as all of the DBEs have the same hashing algorithms, that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem, so here is a procedure that does the work:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE string_to_ascii(IN inputStr VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  DECLARE strLen INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE current_char VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE current_char_ascii VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE outputStr TEXT;
  
  IF inputStr IS NULL THEN
    SET inputStr = '';
  END IF;
  
  SET strLen = CHAR_LENGTH(inputStr);
  SET idx = 1;
    
  WHILE idx <= strLen DO
    SET current_char = SUBSTR(inputStr, idx, 1);
    SET current_char_ascii = ASCII(current_char);
    IF idx = 1 THEN
        SET outputStr = current_char_ascii;
    ELSE
        SET outputStr = CONCAT(outputStr, ",", current_char_ascii);
    END IF;
    
    SET idx = idx+1;

  END WHILE;
  
  SELECT outputStr;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Usage:

```
> CALL string_to_ascii('hello');
+---------------------+
| outputStr           |
+---------------------+
| 104,101,108,108,111 |
+---------------------+
```

If you prefer to use it as a function:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION string_to_ascii ( inputStr TEXT )
RETURNS TEXT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE strLen INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE current_char VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE current_char_ascii VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE outputStr TEXT;
  
  IF inputStr IS NULL THEN
    SET inputStr = '';
  END IF;
  
  SET strLen = CHAR_LENGTH(inputStr);
  SET idx = 1;
    
  WHILE idx <= strLen DO
    SET current_char = SUBSTR(inputStr, idx, 1);
    SET current_char_ascii = ASCII(current_char);
    IF idx = 1 THEN
        SET outputStr = current_char_ascii;
    ELSE
        SET outputStr = CONCAT(outputStr, ",", current_char_ascii);
    END IF;
    
    SET idx = idx+1;

  END WHILE;
  
  RETURN outputStr;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

And then the usage will be:

```
> SELECT string_to_ascii('hello');
+--------------------------+
| string_to_ascii('hello') |
+--------------------------+
| 104,101,108,108,111      |
+--------------------------+
```